# Como separar un array de numeros donde los numeros sean similares

Tags: javascript

Un ejemplo seria lo siguiente

```
let n = [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,1];
```

lo que quiero es separarlos en numero iguales en array diferentes

```
let a =[1,1,1,1];
let b =[2,2,2];
let c =[3];
```

la verdad es que no se me ocurre como hacerlo, por que quiero que funcione con cualquier array, y podria separarlos con arrays con estos tres numeros en especifico, pero con cualquier array de numeros no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Un array de números repetidos no tiene mucho sentido, así que no estoy seguro de entender (o si entendiste) el problema. Podrías explicar el contexto de porque quieres hacer esto?

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Primero, te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que conozcas como funciona la comunidad. Segundo, por favor ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que has intentado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así

```js
const n = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1];
const groupedNumbers = {};

n.forEach((number) => {
  if (!(number in groupedNumbers)) {
     groupedNumbers[number] = [];
  }
  
  groupedNumbers[number].push(number);
});

console.log(groupedNumbers);
```

Utilizas un objeto que almacene como llave el número que encuentras y cuyo valor sea un arreglo, entonces cada vez que encuentras un número lo vas a gregando al arreglo que corresponda

Comment: hola gracias, lo que quería era hacer algo como eso, por ejemplo que cada numero dentro del array represente una media de un color y ver cuantos pares hay ejemplo:

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ejemplo-pares-2xep6  no se si hay una forma de hacerlo mas fácil con programación funcional como map y filters me gustaría que me ayuden a mejorar el código para que quede mas elegante